# Aligning several captions to the left

Tags: alignment

I was trying to align my caption in https://www.overleaf.com/14116991zfbttpsgjsym#/54641567/
to the left. But I can't use `\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}`
Since I only want several caption to be aligned to the left. 
Interestingly, if you delete all the code before begin document and replace it by

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{animate}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
```

Then the caption will be aligned automatically (in central). Anyway I just want my caption to be aligned/ looks neat.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `\captionsetup` several times in your document

Answer (score 1):

`\captionsetup` can also be used locally:

- A large group:

  ```
  \begingroup
     \captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
     ...
  \endgroup
  ```
- or inside the floating environment:

  ```
  \begin{figure}
    \captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
    \caption{...}
  \end{figure}
  ```